# How to launch Python Interactive Shell from python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am designing a context menu, in which I use a context menu to redirect to my python script.

Among multiple other options, one option is to launch interactive shell from the script with pre-import commands.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Created Script which imports the pre-requisites `start-script.py` consists like below:

```py
import os
import sys

MY_MODULE_PATH = "<path/to/my/module>"
sys.path.append("MY_MODULE_PATH")

# follows the imports from module
# ...
# ...
```

2. Code-block handling to invoke script to launch as startup

```py
    import subprocess
    startup_script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "start-script.py")
    cmd = [sys.executable, "-i", startup_script]
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

Is this is the only way or more better and simple approach then these 2 steps and files?